# Constructivist Interpretation of a Function

Tags: logic, philosophy, constructive-mathematics

Lets suppose I have an exponential function $a^{x}$, and I desire to show that for any number $n$ in $(0, \infty)$, it is possible to find a value of $x_0$ such that $a^{x_0} = n$. The simplest proof would be to construct a function that does exactly that.

```
Real findLogarithm(Exponential f, PositiveReal n) {
    Real x_0 = new Real();
    /* ... */
    return x_0;
}
```

According to the lambda calculus, the type signature of this function would be

$\mathrm{findLogarithm} :: \mathrm{Exponential} \rightarrow (\mathrm{PositiveReal} \rightarrow \mathrm{Real})$

However, an equally valid type signature, in the language of first order logic, would be

$\forall x \forall y \exists ! z (P(z))$,

where P(z) is the desired invariant that results from constructing the function. If so, then can we interpret the function construction operator in the Lambda Calculus as a type of predicate in first-order logic? I am trying to find a motivation for why it is that, out of the 16 possible logical connectives, the lambda calculus gives the logical implication a privileged position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $\forall x:X\forall y:Y\exists !z:Z P(x,y,z)$ then by the (higher-type) axiom of choice there exists a unique functional $\Phi\colon X\to (Y\to Z)$ such that $\forall x,y P(x,y,\Phi(x,y))$, and vice-versa. So your two formulations are just different ways of saying the same thing.

However, any restrictions you put on $\Phi$ (e.g. computable, primitive recursive) will correspond to a restriction on the $P$ (e.g. quantifier-free, provable in Peano arithmetic). In fact the precise correspondence between the two formulations is an incredibly deep question in proof theory.

As for your second point: The different logical connectives are largely interchangeable. For instance $A\rightarrow B\Leftrightarrow \neg A\lor B$, and so you could write down the axioms of propositional logic without referring explicitly to $\rightarrow$. What you choose depends on style and presentation to a certain extent. The $\lambda$-calculus is a theory of functionals, and so the underlying logic tends to be presented with an emphasis on $\rightarrow$.

Comment: +1. It's also the case that $\to$ has a different meaning in constructive mathematics. The [BHK interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer%E2%80%93Heyting%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_interpretation) gives a meaning to each of the connectives, and $\to$ does have a privileged role in that interpretation. So in systems where they want to use the [Curry--Howard isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) in $\lambda$ calculus, they will need to follow the constructive meanings of things.

Comment: In classical propositional logic, I can understand the choice behind selecting the basic connectives, because the choice must be functionally complete. However, in intuitionistic logic, the only reason I can see behind the choice of $\rightarrow$, $\land$, $\lor$, and $\bot$ is essentially consensus; there's no way to speak of functional completeness in intuitionistic logic under the BHK interpretation. So why is this set of operators so privileged, especially considering that in classical logic this operator set isn't even minimally functionally complete!

Comment: What would you replace them with?

Comment: @TOstojich: if you want to work in constructive logic, it's better to break the habit of thinking of things like truth values and functional completeness. The reason for the connectives in constructive logic is based on mathematical practice. The core concepts of math include "and", "or", "if/then", and "the following is known to tbe impossible".

Comment: @CarlMummert, is it valid to ask what it means to be a core concept of math?

Comment: @TOstojich - in *intuitionistic* or *conctructive* logic and math we use the basic "concepts" (like : →, ∧, ∨, and ⊥) necessary for building an argument and a proof with different meaning from their *classical* version, but we need them.